# WordPress prevent delete taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, hook

I would like to prevent that some categories are accidentally deleted. For this I use a meta entry for the category to be protected.

I use the following code for this:

```
// edit: wrong hook! ** add_action( 'delete_term_taxonomy', 'taxonomy_delete_protection', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'pre_delete_term', 'taxonomy_delete_protection', 10, 1 );
function taxonomy_delete_protection ( $term_id )
{
    
    if (get_term_meta ($term_id, 'delete-protect', true) === true)
    {
      wp_die('Cannot delete this category');
    }
    
}
```

Unfortunately, instead of my error message, only "Something went wrong" is displayed. Why?

---

Edit: The `delete_term_taxonomy` is the wrong hook for my code, because it deleted the meta before i can check the meta entry. `pre_delete_term` does fire before anything happens with the category.

Answer (score 1):

This is my current solution, not perfect but it works.

The "Something went wrong" message show up if you delete the taxonomy with the row action. So i unset the "delete" action so it couldn't be triggered this way.

```
add_filter ('category_row_actions', 'unset_taxonomy_row_actions', 10, 2);
function unset_taxonomy_row_actions ($actions, $term)
{

$delete_protected = get_term_meta ($term->term_id, 'delete-protect', true);

   if ($delete_protected)
   {
    unset ($actions['delete']);
   }

return $actions;
}
```

Then i hide the "Delete" Link in the taxonomy edit form with css. It's still could be triggered if you inspect the site and it's link, but there is no hook to remove this action otherwise.

```
add_action( 'category_edit_form', 'remove_delete_edit_term_form', 10, 2 );

function remove_delete_edit_term_form ($term, $taxonomy)
{

    $delete_protected = get_term_meta ($term->term_id, 'delete-protect', true);
    
    if ($delete_protected)
    {
        // insert css
        echo '<style type="text/css">#delete-link {display: none !important;}</style>';
    }
    
}
```

Finally the check before deleting the taxonomy. This should catch all other ways, like the bulk action "delete". I didn't found another way yet to stop the script from deleting the taxonomy.

```
add_action ('pre_delete_term', 'taxonomy_delete_protection', 10, 1 );

function taxonomy_delete_protection ( $term_id )
{
    
    $delete_protected = get_term_meta ($term_id, 'delete-protect', true);
    
    if ($delete_protected)
    {
        $term = get_term ($term_id);

        $error = new WP_Error ();
        $error->add (1, '<h2>Delete Protection Active!</h2>You cannot delete "' . $term->name . '"!');
        wp_die ($error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but I don't see the error message. 
So, I just used wp_die( -1 ), which generates a default message "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that". 
Also, you can use wp_die( 0 ), which generates "Something went wrong.".

Answer (score 0):

The "Why" is because of the [following](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/js/tags.js#L42-L65) JavaScript that ships with WordPress:

```
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(r){
    if ( '1' == r ) {
        $('#ajax-response').empty();
        tr.fadeOut('normal', function(){ tr.remove(); });

        /**
         * Removes the term from the parent box and the tag cloud.
         *
         * `data.match(/tag_ID=(\d+)/)[1]` matches the term ID from the data variable.
         * This term ID is then used to select the relevant HTML elements:
         * The parent box and the tag cloud.
         */
        $('select#parent option[value="' + data.match(/tag_ID=(\d+)/)[1] + '"]').remove();
        $('a.tag-link-' + data.match(/tag_ID=(\d+)/)[1]).remove();

    } else if ( '-1' == r ) {
        $('#ajax-response').empty().append('<div class="error"><p>' + wp.i18n.__( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.' ) + '</p></div>');
        tr.children().css('backgroundColor', '');

    } else {
        $('#ajax-response').empty().append('<div class="error"><p>' + wp.i18n.__( 'Something went wrong.' ) + '</p></div>');
        tr.children().css('backgroundColor', '');
    }
});
```

The expected response to this POST request is:

- `'1'` if the term was deleted
- `'-1'` if your user doesn't have permission to delete the term.

For all other cases, "Something went wrong" is displayed.

You are terminating the script early with `wp_die`, yielding an unexpected response, which comes under "other cases".

There isn't a way to provide a custom error message in the notice box here without writing some JavaScript of your own.

Comment: What else can i do instead of wp_die? It seems that the hook does not react on any return value.

Comment: It does not. As mentioned in the answer, *"There isn't a way to provide a custom error message in the notice box here without writing some JavaScript of your own."*

Answer (score 0):

This solution provides a way to disable **all** categories from being deleted by a non Admin. This is for anyone like myself who's been searching.

```
function disable_delete_cat() {
  global $wp_taxonomies;
  if(!current_user_can('administrator')){ 
  $wp_taxonomies[ 'category' ]->cap->delete_terms = 'do_not_allow';
  }
}
add_action('init','disable_delete_cat');
```

Comment: Thanks for that info about all categories. But isn't it then the same if I simply take away this right from the other user roles except the admin via a role manager?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution (that will automatically take care of all different places where you can possibly delete the category/term) and in my opinion the most flexible one is using the `user_has_cap` hook:

```
function maybeDoNotAllowDeletion($allcaps, $caps, array $args, $user)
{
    if ($args[0] !== 'delete_term') return $allcaps;

    // you can skip protection for any user here
    // let's say that for the default admin with id === 1
    if ($args[1] === 1) return $allcaps;

    $termId = $args[2];
    $term = get_term($termId);

    // you can skip protection for all taxonomies except
    // some special one - let's say it is called 'sections'
    if ($term->taxonomy !== 'sections') return $allcaps;

    // you can protect only selected set of terms from
    // the 'sections' taxonomy here
    $protectedTermIds = [23, 122, 3234];
    
    if (in_array($termId, $protectedTermIds )) {
      $allcaps['delete_categories'] = false;
      // if you have some custom caps set
      $allcaps['delete_sections'] = false;
    }

    return $allcaps;
}
add_filter('user_has_cap', 'maybeDoNotAllowDeletion', 10, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but an administrator should still have all rights, including deleting the taxonomy. My solution was an additional option field for the taxonomy, which must first be deselected before the taxonomy can be deleted. This should prevent an admin from deleting it by mistake.  In my example, this was the if query with the $delete_protected